# License Model on AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to deploy an RDS Instance on AWS via Terraform.

I'm deploying a SQL-Server and I'm getting this error message:

```
│ Error: Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterCombination: RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.t3.large, Engine=sqlserver-se, EngineVersion=15.00.4073.23.v1, LicenseModel=license-included. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation.
│   status code: 400, request id: ec56ea02-4002-454c-bb51-2eaff3ed99d3
```

My Current Code is:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "sql_server_instance" {
  allocated_storage    = "160"
  engine               = "sqlserver-se"
  engine_version       = "15.00.4073.23.v1"
  license_model        = "license-included"
  instance_class       = "db.t3.large"
  name                 = "rds-${var.environment}-sqlserver-01"
  username             = "${var.environment}rdsmaster"
  password             = random_password.password.result
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.subnet_group.name

  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.sql_sg.id,
  ]

  depends_on = [
    aws_security_group.sql_sg,
  ]
}
```

I can't find good examples of what someone has created above nor the default values. I've checked on AWS and gone for the parameter that is used.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue here is the `instance_class` used for the database, `db.t3.large` is not supported for `sqlserver-se` engine with version of `15.00.4073.23.v1`.

You can check the supported instance classes by lookin the the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html), or by running the following AWS CLI command (which also can be found in the same docs):

```sh
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options \
--engine sqlserver-se --engine-version 15.00.4073.23.v1 \
--query "*[].{DBInstanceClass:DBInstanceClass,StorageType:StorageType}|[?StorageType=='gp2']|[].{DBInstanceClass:DBInstanceClass}" \
--output text \
--region us-east-1
```

This will print all the supported instance classes. If you want to use something from the `t3` burstable family, you can chose between:

```
db.t3.2xlarge
db.t3.xlarge
```